# Unable to mount the component in react class based components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react 16.8 I made a project using hooks and functional components and now I am trying to make it Into class based components but one component is not getting mounted. In app.js I am fetching data in componentDidUpdate which is working fine with no Issues. Element.js is also rendering the components and creating the links onclick I am updating state and call the popup component by passing props which is not working.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Element from './components/Element';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { elements: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const res = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('/data');
      const data = result.data;
      this.setState({ elements: data });
    };
    res();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div id='table'>
          {this.state.elements.map(element => (
            <Element elements={element} key={element._id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Element.js I am creating links for all the elements and creating the routing part. Onclick make showpopup true and pass the props to popup.
When popup is called outside route it is working. But on each component click I have to pass different props and show popup for the same.
**Element.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Popup from './Popup';
class Element extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showPopup: false };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showPopup: !this.state.showPopup });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          title={this.props.elements.name}
          className={`element element-${this.props.elements.number} ${this.props.elements.category}`}
        >
          {' '}
          <Link to={this.props.elements.name}>
            <div className='symbol'>{this.props.elements.symbol}</div>
          </Link>
          {this.state.showPopup ? (
            <Route
              exact
              path='/:this.props.elements.name'
              component={props => <Popup element={this.props.elements} />}
            />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to='/' />
          )}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Element;
```

**Popup.js**//Not getting mounted

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Popup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.element);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='popup'>
        <center>
          <div className={`popupInner ${this.props.elements.category}`}>
            {Object.entries(this.props.elements).map(([key, val]) => (
              <h2 key={key}>
                {key}: {val ? val : 'unknown'}
              </h2>
            ))}
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Popup;
```

Here is one of the JSON

```
appearance: "colorless gas"
atomic_mass: 1.008
boil: 20.271
category: "diatomic nonmetal"
color: null
density: 0.08988
discovered_by: "Henry Cavendish"
electron_affinity: 72.769
electron_configuration: "1s1"
electronegativity_pauling: 2.2
ionization_energies: [1312]
melt: 13.99
molar_heat: 28.836
name: "Hydrogen"
named_by: "Antoine Lavoisier"
number: 1
period: 1
phase: "Gas"
shells: [1]
source: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen"
spectral_img: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Spectra.jpg"
summary: "Hydrogen is a chemical element with chemical symbol H and atomic number 1. With an atomic weight of 1.00794 u, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table. Its monatomic form (H) is the most abundant chemical substance in the Universe, constituting roughly 75% of all baryonic mass."
symbol: "H"
xpos: 1
ypos: 1
_id: "5d90c80f6adf8a1c62f4fdb4"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong part.

```
 path='/:this.props.elements.name'
```

It should be like below:

```
 path={`/:${this.props.elements.name}`}
```

Comment: this answer works but there is another issue when I hit refresh the showpopup becomes false and gets redirected to /. If I was supposed to show the popup even on reload what do you suggest I could do. Can you show that code as well?

Comment: as you have initialized showpopup in constructor so it getting call every time. remove it from constructor and put outside.

Answer (score 1):

The path you have provided is just a string so change it to expression like below.

```
<Route
  exact
  path={`/:${this.props.elements.name}`}
  component={props => <Popup element={this.props.elements} />}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

From this link (https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components):

> When you use the component props, the router uses React.createElement
>   to create a new React element from the given component. That means if
>   you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would
>   create a new component every render. This results in the existing
>   component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just
>   updating the existing component.

So your line element.js must be

```
 render={props => <Popup element={this.props.elements} />}
```

instead of this.

```
 component={props => <Popup element={this.props.elements} />}
```

Also the path mus tbe corrected to:

path={`/:${this.props.elements.name}`}

Comment: Technically  it will work, but performanca problems. Please have a look to the tutorial I gave in the answer.